# How many students are involved in the question "How do students actually learn from each other?", two or more than two?

Tags: grammaticality, usage

In Bill Bryson's book titled "Mother Tongue. The Story of the English Language", on page 132 it says that "we must use *each other* for two things and *one another* for more than two."

So, when I read the following sentence quoted from a nih.gov paper, I wondered whether the writers correctly use *each other*.

From the point of view of a learner, like I am, the sentence might be okay only if one assumes that the writers want to mean that students interact each other *in pairs* (only two students at time) even if they are more than two; but, honestly, I doubt that the writers want to mean that.

> Collaborative, case-based learning: how do students actually learn from ***each other***?

Can anybody explain?

Comment: Bill Bryson is quite wrong with respect to both phrases. There might be just a hint of colour to the contrary argument that *one another* logically suggests pairwise reciprocation; but Bryson's position is indefensible.

Answer (score 5):

The *Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary* describes *each other* as follows:

> used as the object of a verb or preposition to show that each member of a group does something to or for the other members

Similar description is given for *one another*.

> *one another* is used when you are saying that each member of a group does something to or for the other people in the group

Two of the examples given for *each other*, and *one another* are the following ones:

> They looked at each other and laughed.

> I think we've learned a lot about one another in this session.

There isn't any note saying that *each other* is used when the group is made of two people, and *one another* when the people in the group are more than two.

Comment: In "They looked at each other and laughed.", it implies two people, since generally people only look at one person, at this level, at a time. As for "I think we've learned a lot about one another in this session.", this sounds to me like something that would be said in a group setting. In this definition http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/session it refers to groups, meetings, classes etc.